# Magento 2 Bank transfer payment method is not shown on checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-banktransfer

I have enabled Bank Transfer payment method on backend by still is not shown on checkout.
I flushed the cache and I made sure that the payment method is enabled for the shop.
This happened after upgrade to 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

***DISCLAIMER***: I don't recommend this as a fix so please DO NOT do this on a PRODUCTION magento website.

I had the same problem on **Magento Community v2.2.7** and found that my active payment methods were all being filtered by a method: `private function filterList(array $list)` in file `vendor/magento/module-vault/Model/PaymentMethodList.php`.

Unfortunately I can't tell you how to fix it "properly", but I was able to hack this file to get them to show up for my POC by changing line 73 in the above file from:

`return $methodInstance instanceof VaultPaymentInterface;`

TO:

`return !($methodInstance instanceof VaultPaymentInterface);`

I'm fairly new to Magento and don't understand Vault payments fully in terms of Magento specifics, but to my mind the "Bank Transfer" payment method should not be seen as a vault payment method. Based on the docblock above the method: "Filter vault methods from payments", I believe this is a bug and the condition used in the filtering should be inverted by the Magento dev team.

Answer (score 0):

But if you do not recommend doing it in production, it is worth modifying it in the development environment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199202)